# Connecting SQL Server in JAVA using Eclipse, Error: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, sql-server, database, eclipse, jdbc

Goal is to connect to MS SQL Server database using Java and perform some SQL statements.
Issue while finding the class, Error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

tried both classname `com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver` AND `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

Classpath also set in Eclipse to:

```
CLASSPATH C:/Program Files/Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1 for SQL Server/sqljdbc_4.1/enu/sqljdbc.jar
```

also changed win7 enviornment variables to:

```
.;C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.1\enu\sqljdbc.jar;C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.1\enu\sqljdbc4.jar;C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.1\enu\sqljdbc41.jar;
```

Used this Code:

```
package edu.umt.oop.lecture7;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class databasepro {

    public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        Connection connection = null;
        try
        {
          // the sql server driver string
          Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

          // the sql server url
          String url = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://C-LHE-CS-68541:1433;DatabaseName=CMSA_Console";

          // get the sql server database connection
          connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"sa", "123456");


          System.out.println("\nSuccess");
          // now do whatever you want to do with the connection
          // ...

        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.exit(1);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.exit(2);
        }
      }


}
```

Complete Error thrown is :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at edu.umt.oop.lecture7.databasepro.main(databasepro.java:15)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253551/classpath-set-but-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-microsoft-sqlserver-jd

Comment: Applications rarely use the classpath environment variables. You need to add **one** and only one of the SQL Server jars (preferably `sqljdbc41.jar`) to the build path of your application (if run from Eclipse), or to the runtime class path when run standalone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the `jar` file. So download `jar` file from below link and this to your project library in IDE e.g. Eclipse.

[Download Jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/sqlserverjdbc/sqlserverjdbc.jar.zip)