# class not found exception in java play framework

Tags: java, sql-server, playframework, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to create an app in play framework using ms sql server and java and i am getting `[ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]` exception anyone please send me the link if u see a similar application .Just need to connect to database and fetch data

Comment: possible duplicate of [Classpath set, but: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253551/classpath-set-but-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-microsoft-sqlserver-jd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `build.sbt` paste the following code:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "sqljdbc4" % "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

val appDependencies = Seq(
    "sqljdbc4" % "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
)