# i need to print only the date (dd/mm/yyyy ) but now am getting (dd/mm/yyyy and time)

Tags: jsp, date, datetime

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="460"  bgcolor="#EEFFCA">
<tr>
<td width="100%"><font size="6" color="#008000">&nbsp;Date Example</font>    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100%"><b>&nbsp;Current Date and time is:&nbsp; <font  color="#FF0000">
<%= new java.util.Date() %>
</font></b></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i need to print the date in the format dd//mm/yyyy
how can i get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
<%= new java.util.Date() %>
```

use

```
<%= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new java.util.Date())%>
```

**Note** : You need to import [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) in your jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>
```

Comment: How i can connect ms sql server in jsp ?  I have add jar file for ms sql. but shows an error  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1856)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1705)
Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253551/classpath-set-but-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-microsoft-sqlserver-jd it might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `SimpleDateFormat` to format your output:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(dateFormat.parse(<your date object>)));
```